# ACER: optimization using the KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning

In Page 5 [Sample Efficient Actor-Critic with Experience Replay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01224), the authors define an optimization problem with a linearized KL divergence constraint (Eq.11)as follow
$$
\min_z{1\over 2}\Vert \hat g_t^{acer}-z\Vert_2^2\\
s.t.k^Tz\le\delta\\
where\quad k=\nabla_{\phi_\theta}D_{KL}[f(\cdot|\phi_{\theta_a}(x_t))\Vert f(\cdot|\phi_{\theta}(x_t))] 
$$
where $f(\cdot|\phi_{\theta_a}(x_t))$ denotes the policy network, $f$ alone is the categorical distribution. $\phi_{\theta_a}$ is the average policy network, whose parameters are updated according to: $\theta_a\leftarrow\alpha\theta_a+(1-\alpha)\theta$.
They solve this quadratic programming problem, getting the solution:
$$
z^*=\hat g_t^{acer}-\max\left\{0, {k^T\hat g_t^{acer}-\delta\over \Vert k\Vert_2^2}\right\}k\tag 1
$$
I cannot see how they get this. where does the maximum term come from? To my best knowledge, the KKT conditions can be written as
$$
\begin{align}
z-\hat g_t^{acer}+\lambda k&=0\\
\lambda(k^Tz-\delta)&=0\\
\lambda&\ge0
\end{align}
$$
from which I get
$$
z^*=\begin{cases}
k^{-1}\delta&\mathrm{if}\ \lambda>0\\
\hat g_t^{acer}&\mathrm{if}\ \lambda=0
\end{cases}
$$
This seems not consistent with Equation1. Where do I make mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulating Lagrange function as
$$
L(z, \lambda) = \frac{1}{2} || \hat g_{t}^{acer} - z ||^2 - \lambda \left( k^T z - \delta \right), \quad \lambda \leq 0.
$$

The KKT conditions should be:
\begin{aligned}
z-\hat g_t^{acer}- \frac{1}{2} \lambda k&=0 \quad (1)\\
k^Tz-\delta&=0 \quad(2)\\
\lambda&\le 0 \quad(3)
\end{aligned}
Thus, from (1), $z = \hat g_t^{acer} + \frac{1}{2} \lambda k$, substituting $z$ in (2), obtaining: $k^{T} (\hat g_t^{acer} + \frac{1}{2} \lambda k) - \delta = 0$.

We can get 
$$
\lambda = \frac{2 (\delta - k^{T} \hat g_t^{acer})}{||k||^{2}} \quad (4)
$$
combining (3) and (1), the solution should be:

\begin{aligned}
z^{*} 
&= \hat g_{t}^{acer} + \min \left\{ 0, \frac{ \delta - k^{T} \hat g_t^{acer}}{||k||^{2}} \right\} k \\
&= \hat g_{t}^{acer} - \max \left\{ 0, \frac{ k^{T} \hat g_t^{acer} - \delta}{||k||^{2}} \right\} k \\
\end{aligned}